# Finding HTML element and moving cursor to element returning wrong position

Tags: html, css, vba

As the title suggests I am trying to move my mouse cursor to an element in a HTML document, some details I think I should share first:

1. Browser: Internet Explorer 11
2. IDE: Ms Excel VBA
3. Monitor resolution: Single monitor and dual monitor (extended), both resolution 1920x1080

I am using `getBoundingClientRect` to get the HTML element position and `ClientToScreen` to map that location to screen location and finally `SetCursorPos` to set the mouse position. The problem I am facing is that it looks like there is always a non-fixed offset somewhere moving my cursor to the wrong location. Even when trying on a website such as Google's homepage.

From troubleshooting, placing my mouse at the tip of the IE content area (presumable location 0,0 for `getBoundingClientRect`) the results show that after running `ClientToScreen` the location of Y is off but quite a few pixels.

```
Set to (0,0) position X: 0 ; Y:0  'Manually set variables to 0,0 position
GetCursorPos X: 2400 ; Y:161  'Placed my mouse at the presumed 0,0 position for reference
ClientToScreen position X: 2400 ; Y:-10   'After ClientToScreen position Y position is not as expected, at least to me
```

Below is the code I used, you can simply open an IE window and navigate to http://www.google.com then run the macro.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ClientToScreen Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10

Public Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

Sub test()
    Dim testDoc     As HTMLDocument
    Dim testDiv     As HTMLDivElement
    Dim ieWindow    As InternetExplorer
    Dim hwnd        As Long
    Dim pntCursor   As POINTAPI
    Dim pntRet      As Long
    Dim curPos      As POINTAPI

    For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        With w
            If .Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
                Set ieWindow = w
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next w


    Set testDoc = ieWindow.document
    Set testDiv = testDoc.getElementById("hplogo")

    hwnd = 0
    hwnd = FindWindow("IEFrame", vbNullString)

    pntCursor.X = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().Left
    pntCursor.Y = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().Top

    pntRet = ClientToScreen(hwnd, pntCursor)

    pntRet = SetCursorPos(pntCursor.X, pntCursor.Y)

    SetCursorPosition = (pntRet <> 0)

    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 0&, 0&, 0&, 0&

End Sub
```

Here I am trying to move the cursor to the Google Logo but this is where my mouse ends up (top left of the right click menu).
[image: Code results]

I've already spent 3 days on just this issue and cannot find enough details online that explains this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An alternative might be to use UIAutomation or selenium basic vba

Comment: I am unfamiliar with UIAutomation, but I have heard of Selenium though no experience using it. I am actually creating this tool to be shared with a small team of colleagues to help automate some of our works so trying to avoid the need for them to have to install additional software/dlls including browsers. Plus writing this and using this on company equipment and want to avoid cyber security issues from unauthorized software installations. Basically I've got to work with what I've got.